# What are the benefits of defining and calling a function inside another function in R?

Tags: r, performance, function

**Approach 1**

```
f1 <- function(x)
{
    # Do calculation xyz ....

    f2 <- function(y)
    {
        # Do stuff...
        return(some_object)
    }

    return(f2(x))
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
f2 <- function(y)
{
    # Do stuff...

    return(some_object)
}

f3 <- function(x)
{
    # Do calculation xyz ....
    return(f2(x))
}
```

Assume `f1` and `f3` both do the same calculations and give the same result.

Are there any *significant* advantages in using approach 1, calling `f1()`, vs approach 2, calling `f3()`?

Is a certain approach more favourable when:

- large data is being passed in and/or out of  `f2`?
- Speed is a big issue. E.g. `f1` or `f3` are called repeatedly in simulations.

(Approach 1 seems common in packages, defining inside another)

One advantage of using the approach `f1` is that `f2` won't exist outside `f1` once `f1` has finished being called (and `f2` is only called in `f1` or `f3`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Benefits of defining `f2` inside `f1`:

- `f2` only visible within `f1`, useful if `f2` is only meant for use within `f1`, though within package namespaces this is debatable since you just wouldn't export `f2` if you defined it outside
- `f2` has access to variables within `f1`, which could be considered a good or a bad thing:

  - good, because you don't have to pass variables through the function interface and you can use `<<-` to implement stuff like memoization, etc.
  - bad, for the same reasons...

Disadvantages:

- `f2` needs to be redefined every time you call `f1`, which adds some overhead (not very much overhead, but definitely there)

Data size should not matter since R won't copy the data unless it is being modified under either scenario.  As noted in disadvantages, defining `f2` outside of `f1` should be a little faster, especially if you are repeating an otherwise relatively low overhead operation many times.  Here is an example:

```
> fun1 <- function(x) {
+   fun2 <- function(x) x
+   fun2(x)
+ }
> fun2a <- function(x) x
> fun3 <- function(x) fun2a(x)
> 
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
+   fun1(TRUE), fun3(TRUE)
+ )
Unit: nanoseconds
       expr min    lq median    uq   max neval
 fun1(TRUE) 656 674.5  728.5 859.5 17394   100
 fun3(TRUE) 406 434.5  480.5 563.5  1855   100
```

In this case we save 250ns (edit: the difference is actually 200ns; believe it or not the extra set of `{}` that `fun1` has costs another 50ns).  Not much, but can add up if the interior function is more complex or you repeat the function many many times.

Answer (score 5):

You would typically use approach 2. Some exceptions are

1. Function closures:

   ```
   f = function() {
       counter = 1
       g = function() {
           counter <<- counter + 1
           return(counter)
       }
    }
    counter = f()
    counter()
    counter()
   ```

   Function closure enable us to remember the state.
2. Sometimes it's handy to only define functions as they are only used in one place. For example, when using `optim`, we often tweak an existing function. For example,

   ```
   pdf = function(x, mu) dnorm(x, mu, log=TRUE)
   f = function(d, lower, initial=0) {
     ll = function(mu) {
       if(mu < lower) return(-Inf)
       else -sum(pdf(d, mu))
     }
     optim(initial, ll)
   }

   f(d, 1.5)
   ```

   The `ll` function uses the data set `d` and a lower bound. This is both convenient since this may be the only time we use/need the `ll` function.

Answer (score 0):

An example of what is mentioned in existing answers is probably what I now think of as being the most useful benefit of defining a function in the environment of another function. In simple terms:  You can define functions without specifying all the parameters used inside it, provided those parameters are defined somewhere in the environment in which the function is defined. A nice reference for function environments is of course: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html

This approach can be handy for breaking up blocks of code in a function, where multiple variables might be required and referred to within the function body, into a bunch of sub functions in the function's environment, allowing for cleaner representation of the code, without having to write out a potentially long parameter list.

A simple dummy example below highlights the point

```
f1 <- function(x)
{
  f2 <- function(y)
  {
    # possibly long block of code relevant to the meaning of what `f2` represents
    y + a + b + d
  }

  # might be 10+ variables in special cases
  a <- 10
  b <- 5
  d <- 1

  f2(x)
}

#test:
> f1(100)
[1] 116
```

You can't use this approach if you define the functions with separate parent environments:

```
f3 <- function(x)
{
  a <- 10
  b <- 5
  d <- 1

  f2a(x)
}

f2a <- function(y)
{
  y + a + b + d
}

> f3(100)
Error in f2a(x) : object 'a' not found
```