# Function inside function in R

Tags: r, performance, function

This thread discusses two basic approaches to using functions inside other functions in R: [What are the benefits of defining and calling a function inside another function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331499/what-are-the-benefits-of-defining-and-calling-a-function-inside-another-function)

The top answer says the second approach, naming externally and just calling via name in the outer function, is faster: " `f2` needs to be redefined every time you call `f1`, which adds some overhead (not very much overhead, but definitely there)". My question is, is this overhead caused by the assignment itself or by passing through the function itself?

For example, consider this third option besides the two in that thread:

```
#Approach 1
fun1a <- function(x) {
  fun1b <- function(y){return(y^2)}
  return(fun1b(x))
}

#Approach 2
fun2a <- function(y){return(y^2)}
fun2b <- function(x){return(fun2a(x))}

#Approach 3
fun3 <- function(x) {
  return(function(x){return(x^2)})
}
```

It was confirmed that Approach 2 is faster than Approach 1 because Approach 1 needs to redefine `fun1b` in the function repeatedly. But if you use Approach 3 --basically, Approach 1, but not assigning `fun1b` to a named function everytime you run it -- is that always faster?

If so, why would anyone not just use Approach 3 for everything? i.e. what disadvantages does it have compared to Approach 2 (or 1)

Comment: For me, it mostly boils down to the fact that if you're using a "one off" function (like in approach 3), you are not able to use it anywhere else. Which is fine, if that's your problem you're trying to solve (something like a lambda function in Python). I usually don't worry about performance, whereas code readability is at the top of my list.

Comment: Approach 3 returns a function. When you use that function it will only process itself (in this case compute a square), therefore, it will be the fastest of the three approaches.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik thanks--so the only advantage would be to avoid code repetition elsewhere if you want to use the internal function again?

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks--so in what context(s) would you use Approach (1 or) 2 instead?

Comment: All 3 approaches have their use cases, ap1 can make code simpler to read and maintain, ap2 can be used when the two functions stand for themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Some of these (but not all) are already mentioned in the link in the question but here is a longer list.

1. **Visibility**  Functions defined within functions are not visible outside that function increasing the modularity of the software if that function is not also used elsewhere.  It provides a sort of poor man's namespace.  For example, an alternative to using an anonymous function in a `lapply` appearing within a function would be to define it as a named function within the outer function to keep it from being visible outside the outer function.  The name might form a sort of documentation for the inner function.
2. **Scope**  Functions defined within functions can access variables defined in the outer function without passing them as arguments.
3. **Cache** Functions defined within functions and passed back out can use the outer function to cache results so that they are remembered the next time the passed out function is run.  Here `makeIncr` is a factory function which constructs a new counter function each time it is run.  The counter functions return the next number in sequence each time they are run.

   ```
   makeIncr <- function(init) function() { init <<- init + 1; init }
   counter1 <- makeIncr(0)
   counter1()
   ## [1] 1
   counter1()
   ## [1] 2
   counter2 <- makeIncr(0)
   counter2()
   ## [1] 1
   ```
4. **Object Orientation** Functions defined within functions can be used to emulate a limited form of object orientation.  See an example by running:  `demo(scoping)`

Debugging can be a bit more awkward with functions within functions. For example, `debug(makeIncr)` using `makeIncr` above does not debug the counters which would have to be debugged separately.

I am not sure that the performance issue discussed is really material since the functions would be byte compiled the first time the outer function is run.  In most cases you would want to make a decision based on other factors.